# Nuget Package install/update fails with error "Id is required" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package, sendgrid

I am using VS 2010. Want to install Sendgrid Nuget package.

So on package manage console I give following command.

```
PM> Install-Package Sendgrid
```

which gives error as follows:

```
Id is required.
Version is required.
Authors is required.
Description is required.
```

Even if  try this from solution explorer, by adding package reference online, it gives same error.

How can I download this Sendgrid package?

Comment: Can you install other NuGet packages? What version of NuGet are you using?

Comment: This is a generic error faced while updating nuget pakages in Visual studio 2010 when the newer version of package is build using visual studio 2012. The title of this question should be changed I think.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar issues on Visual Studio 2010 and later found that same pkg can be installed via Visual Studio 2012. Most probably you need to update your Nuget pkg manager in Visual Studio 2010.

Go to Tools -> Extension Manager -> Updates -> Update Nuget

In my case I had to update from version 1.0.11220.104 to 2.5.40416.9020.

Another thing I would like to point that you might face this error while trying to update Nuget.

"The signature on the update version of 'NuGet Package Manager' does not match the signature on the installed version."

In that case, uninstall Nuget, restart VS 2010 and install Nuget again. Source: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues